# file_get_content doesnt get my values for address field after space

Tags: php

For some reason, `file_get_contents()` is not returning any results.

Here is my code:

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost/service/service.php?action=register&name='.$name.'&lname='.$lname.'&email='.$email.'&username='.$username.'&password='.$password.'&gender='.$gender.'&mobile='.$mobile.'&address='.$address);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to encode your variables in order to create a valid URL.

Use the function [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php).

```
$name = urlencode($name);
$lname = urlencode($lname);
$email = urlencode($email);
$username = urlencode($username);
$password = urlencode($password);
$gender = urlencode($gender);
$mobile = urlencode($mobile);
$address = urlencode($address);

$result = file_get_contents('http://localhost/service/service.php?action=register&name='.$name.'&lname='.$lname.'&email='.$email.'&username='.$username.'&password='.$password.'&gender='.$gender.'&mobile='.$mobile.'&address='.$address);
```